# pelican model in gazebo

Tags: ros, quadcopter, gazebo, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying out Gazebo to (maybe) build a quadrotor simulator and started with the pelican urdf model in the asctec_drivers stack. I manage to spawn the pelican.xml file in gazebo, but no model of the actual quadrotor is shown. Has anyone succesfully used this model in Gazebo already? If so, could you explain me how to use it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11208/pelican-model-in-gazebo/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pelican.xml file is not configured properly to launch in Gazebo. I've managed a quick fix that you can use. You must add  and  tags to the xml file so that Gazebo can provide the correct physics to the model. I've also added  tags to specify physics parameters and colors. I've included an example from my modified file. You can further modify it to improve upon it later, particularly the model dynamics and physics. I hope that this helps.

URDF: [Pelican URDF Example](http://pastebin.com/m3ipBahB)

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-27**:
The best way is if you start a new question with your problem. That way, everyone can benefit from the help.

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2011-12-26**:
Hi,i used your pelican urdf ,but it does not show me the whole quadrotor. What am i doing wrong??@ DimitriProsser : Is there a oppertunity that i can send you my urdf as email?So that you can have a look ? thanks,regards

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-09-15**:
Thanks, that gets me started!